# Delete the words between [], {}, and ()

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

`file1.txt` contains:

```
Thailand,[a] officially the Kingdom of Thailand and formerly known as Siam,[b] is a country in Southeast Asia.
```

I want to delete the words between `[]` and `()`. The expected output is:

```
Thailand, officially the Kingdom of Thailand and formerly known as Siam, is a country in Southeast Asia.
```

This is my code:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
    file1 = file1.read()
test = re.sub(r'[\(\[].*[\)\]]', '', file1)
```

My code deletes all the words between `[a]` and `[b]`. The example output:

```
Thailand is a country in Southeast Asia.
```

Comment: your `.*` is a greedy match, change it to `.*?` and it should work.

Comment: What's *word* there? Can the input contain `[foo (bar)]` or `((x))` for instance?

Comment: Can there be newlines within `(...)` or `[...]`? Do you require a Python solution, or would ordinary Unix text processing tools also be ok? How would unbalanced brackets be handled?

Comment: subject mentions `[]`, `()` and `{}` but body and your attempt only covers `[]` and `()`. Which is it?

Comment: thank you so much my life saver. I change it to  .*? and it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `[.*]` it does a greedy match, so everything from `[a` till `b]` is matched and substituted for the empty string `''`.

When you use `[.?]`, it matches anychar `.` zero or 1 time `?` which are inside `[]`. And so `[a]` and `[b]` are matched.

```py
import re

with open('file1.txt') as file1:
    file1 = file1.read()
test = re.sub(r'[\(\[].?[\)\]]', '', file1)

print(test)
```

Comment: You may want to add some lines of explanation why this approach solves the shortcomings of the OPs original attempt (your post turned up in my "low quality posts" review queue ...)

Comment: Using `[^\]]*` is a bit more efficient than the lazy quantifier on a dot

Comment: Thank you so much. You guys are my life savers!